# Massless rope in a pulley pulled by a person

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

A massless rope passes through a pulley. On each end of the pulley there is a different mass (object). A person grips one of the masses and thus the system comes to equilibrium.

---

How would you describe the force that the person forces on the mass that is being gripped? What is this type of force called?

In other words, how would you describe (or draw) the forces diagram of the mass (object) being gripped?

***Do you draw the arrow (representing the force) downwards or upwards from the object? Why?***

Comment: What do you mean by "repose of the system"? This sounds like a poor translation ... but I can't figure out what you mean. "System is in equilibrium" maybe?

Comment: Have you tried drawing the diagram? There is the force of gravity on the two masses, and the tension in the string. Unless there is an external force to balance the forces of gravity, the system will accelerate (the heavier mass will fall). See how far you get when you make a diagram, and tell us where you get stuck.

Comment: @Floris Yes, sorry. My native language is Spanish.

Comment: No worries - we are trying to help but need to understand the question...

Comment: @Floris Exactly. The external force of the hand gripping one of the masses causes the system to be in equilibrium. My shortest question would be: How would you draw in the diagram the force forced by the hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you grab the block.  If you press down or up on the block to balance, it would be a normal force.  If you grabbed the side of the block, it would be a frictional force.  It really depends on how much detail you want to involve in determining the force by your hand.  You could also just call it $F_{Hand}$ if you really don't care how the force is generated.  Regardless of what you call it, the force required to balance the system will be the same.

Comment: Is there a way to determinate which type of grabbing is from the ones you said, given the information in my question?

Comment: If you grab the heavier block, the force will be upwards; if you grab the lighter block, the force will be downwards. Without additional information you don't know which it is.

Comment: @Floris I thought that another information given wouldn't help but here it is: In equilibrium the tension of the rope is $30N$. After 2 seconds the tension is raised and in the 4th second the tension is lowered. Does that help?

Comment: Well, they use the word Grip which is defined as "take and keep a firm hold of; grasp tightly."  From that I would think it implies you grip the sides but it's a very vague question.  As I said, it really doesn't matter what it's called unless you wanted to calculate something associated with that specific force like a friction coefficient.  Otherwise, just indicating an external force should be enough.

Comment: @GregPetersen At the end, your answer and comments helped me to resolve the question. Thanks!

Comment: If the tension is raised, then lowered, then the system is being slowed down by pulling down on the side with the heavier weight...

Comment: Gripping from the sides produces both a normal force and a frictional force from the hand.